# Координаты по data атрибутам. Яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты

Есть несколько блоков с дата атрибутами:

```
<a class="main-centers__link" data-coord="[55.119646, 61.625318]">
<a class="main-centers__link" data-coord="[55.244650, 61.375281]">
```

С помощью js делаю поиск и по дата атрибутам проставляю точки (дополнительно еще по клику переход к точке, добавление другой инфу в нужный блок)

```
var Placemark = {};

ymaps.ready(function() {

    var activeItem = $('.main-centers__link_active').attr('data-coord');
    activeItem = JSON.parse(activeItem);

    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map-centers', {
        center: activeItem,
        zoom: 17,
        controls: ['zoomControl']
    }, {
        suppressMapOpenBlock: true,
    });
    console.log('3');
    myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

    $('.main-centers__link').each(function() {
        
        var obj = $(this).attr("data-coord");
        obj = JSON.parse(obj);

            myMap.geoObjects
              .add(new ymaps.Placemark(obj, { 
                iconCaption: ''
              }, {
                iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
                iconImageHref: '../img/geo-mark.png',
                iconImageSize: [29, 43],
                iconImageOffset: [-29, -43]
              }));

    }); //each

    $('.main-centers__link').click(function() {
        var objj = $(this).attr('data-coord');
        objj = JSON.parse(objj);
            // console.log(obj);

            myMap.panTo(objj, {
                flying: 2,
                callback: function() {
                    alert('yeap!');
                }
            });

            var addTitle = $(this).find('.title').html();
            var addAddr = $(this).find('.arrd-hide').html();
            var addTels = $(this).find('.tels-hide').html();

            $('.center-addr__title').html(addTitle);
            $('.center-addr__address .addr').html(addAddr);
            $('.center-addr__address .tels__tel').html(addTels);
        });
});
```

По итогу, точки проставились, но не работает клик по ссылке с атрибутами. Причем, ругается не на функцию клика, а на функцию сбора данных:

```
var obj = $(this).attr("data-coord");
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Именно на вторую строку. ЧЯДНТ? Функция клика, если убрать сбор точек, работает
Думаю, что что-то с преобразование, но не могу понять что именно :\ Перепробовал несколько вариантов
Извиняюсь, что без примера на фидле

Спасибо

Comment: `console.log($(this).attr("data-coord"));` ?

Comment: @Igor Сильно не ругайте за незнание, но в консоле черным шрифтом вывелись 2 строки друг под другом. Пробовал перед JSON в консоль вывести - различий нет. Видимо, JSON не преобразовывает, или могу ошибаться

Comment: u значит undefined, значит у вас `var obj = $(this).attr("data-coord");` не работает

Comment: по-моему, яндекс карты этот атрибут удалили.

Comment: @Alex78191 да, скорей всего вы правы. На другом сайте точно также делал, все работало и в один день - слетело. Не подскажите, каким образом тогда можно это решить? Буду очень рад и благодарен

Comment: @Alex78191 Ругается на этот участок кода: obj = JSON.parse(obj); До вызова яндекс карт, есть еще код. Не учел этого, извиняюсь

Comment: Функция `$('.main-centers__link').each(function() {` не должна вызываться при клике на ссылка, она вызывается при инициализации карты

Comment: @Alex78191 А разве нельзя блоки с одним классом сначала перебрать через .each, проставить точки, а потом через .click по блокам с этим же классом перемещаться к точкам? Функция клика не находится в .each

Comment: Для начала минимальный код для воспроизведения ошибки сделайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Alex78191 https://fiddle.jshell.net/hc5m5yL4/13/ Странно, скопировал весь код на фидл - там работает, а на локалке не хочет :\

Comment: @Alex78191Поменял функцию .click и .each местами - заработало как нужно. Но ошибка в консоле так и осталось на JSON в .each функции

Answer (score 0):

С помощью участников и тыканий решилась проблема.
Функцию клика вынес выше .each, т.к. навигация по карте в DOM находится выше блока карты. 
Ошибка в консоле пропала тогда, когда были проставлены ко всем элементам навигации дата-атибуты. 
Кто будет тестить, заранее пропишите всем элементам дата-атрибуты и только потом уже можно тестить
Благодарю всех за помощь! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: `навигация по карте в DOM находится выше блока карты` клик выполняется после инициализации карты. Не легче document ready использовать?